# how to send file objects to servlet using json

Tags: java, javascript, json, servlets

I am new to web programming. My web application can upload files  (uploaded by drag and drop method in javascripts ) and i want to retrieve them in servlet using Json . servlet file only needs the contents of the text files to do the calculation.

Can any one suggest how to do this ?

softwares used - netbeans ,tomcat

Thank you.

Comment: Google it, and then come back if you have problems.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure if you mean rendering your files in servlets or actually downloading them from your browser. I'm going to assume you mean rendering them. If so, then what you have to do is set up a URI which is associated with the content you want to render. Let's say this is a simple "hello world" rendering in the browser. what you would do is set up a URI as such:

localhost:3000/helloWorld.html.jsp

What you do on your back end is then wait to receive a http GET request to "/helloWorld.html.jsp" page, and then have your router send over the correct page. Luckily, with tools such as tomcat, the routing from local host is straight forward enough, and as your comments mentioned this is simple enough to do with the ample resources on the web.

Also an important point, you don't need JSON when using servlets (if i understood your problem correctly). If you want to send over data in a JSON format, then all you would do is modify the above steps to listen for "/sendJSON.html.jsp" (this could be an empty jsp), and you send over JSON from your back end in your response.